# Error in Substrate "use macros in a custom pallet" tutorial

Tags: substrate-node-template, macro

I'm currently trying [this substrate tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/use-macros-in-a-custom-pallet/), but it got stuck.

Following the tutorial, I coded lib.rs file like this.

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
pub use pallet::*;

#[frame_support::pallet]
pub mod pallet {
    use frame_support::pallet_prelude::*;
    use frame_system::pallet_prelude::*;
    use sp_std::vec::Vec; // Step 3.1 will include this in `Cargo.toml`

    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
        type Event: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Event>;
    }
    #[pallet::event]
    #[pallet::generate_deposit(pub(super) fn deposit_event)]
    pub enum Event<T: Config> {
        ClaimCreated(T::AccountId, Vec<u8>),
        ClaimRevoked(T::AccountId, Vec<u8>),
    }
    #[pallet::error]
    pub enum Error<T> {
        ProofAlreadyClaimed,
        NoSuchProof,
        NotProofOwner,
    }
    #[pallet::pallet]
    #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
    pub struct Pallet<T>(_);

    #[pallet::storage]
    pub(super) type Proofs<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, Vec<u8>, (T::AccountId, T::BlockNumber), ValueQuery>;
    #[pallet::hooks]
    impl<T: Config> Hooks<BlockNumberFor<T>> for Pallet<T> {}
    #[pallet::call]
    impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
        #[pallet::weight(1_000)]
        pub fn create_claim(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            proof: Vec<u8>,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
            let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;
            ensure!(!Proofs::<T>::contains_key(&proof), Error::<T>::ProofAlreadyClaimed);
            let current_block = <frame_system::Pallet<T>>::block_number();
            Proofs::<T>::insert(&proof, (&sender, current_block));
            Self::deposit_event(Event::ClaimCreated(sender, proof));
            Ok(())
        }
        #[pallet::weight(10_000)]
        pub fn revoke_claim(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            proof: Vec<u8>,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
            let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;
            ensure!(Proofs::<T>::contains_key(&proof),Error::<T>::NoSuchProof);
            let (owner, _) = Proofs::<T>::get(&proof);
            ensure!(sender == owner, Error::<T>::NotProofOwner);
            Proofs::<T>::remove(&proof);
            Self::deposit_event(Event::ClaimRevoked(sender, proof));
            Ok(())
        }
    }
}
```

Cargo.toml file is like this.

```
[package]
name = "pallet-template"
version = "4.0.0-dev"
description = "FRAME pallet template for defining custom runtime logic."
authors = ["Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>"]
homepage = "https://substrate.io/"
edition = "2021"
license = "Unlicense"
publish = false
repository = "https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/"

[package.metadata.docs.rs]
targets = ["x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"]

[dependencies]
codec = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3.0.0", default-features = false, features = [
    "derive",
] }
scale-info = { version = "2.1.1", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
frame-support = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.26"}
frame-system = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.26" }
frame-benchmarking = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.26", optional = true }

[dev-dependencies]
sp-core = { default-features = false, version = "6.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.26" }
sp-io = { default-features = false, version = "6.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.26" }
sp-runtime = { default-features = false, version = "6.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.26" }

[dependencies.sp-std]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
branch = 'polkadot-v0.9.26' 

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
  "sp-std/std",
    "codec/std",
    "scale-info/std",
    "frame-support/std",
    "frame-system/std",
    "frame-benchmarking/std",
]

runtime-benchmarks = ["frame-benchmarking/runtime-benchmarks"]
try-runtime = ["frame-support/try-runtime"]
```

And I used command "cargo check -p node-template-runtime". But I got an Error like this.

```
ensure!(!Proofs::<T>::contains_key(&proof), Error::<T>::ProofAlreadyClaimed);
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item cannot be called on 
`frame_support::pallet_prelude::StorageMap<_GeneratedPrefixForStorageProofs<T>, frame_support::Blake2_128Concat, Vec<u8>, (<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <T as frame_system::Config>::BlockNumber), frame_support::pallet_prelude::ValueQuery>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds

Proofs::<T>::insert(&proof, (&sender, current_block));
             ^^^^^^ function or associated item cannot be called on `frame_support::pallet_prelude::StorageMap<_GeneratedPrefixForStorageProofs<T>, frame_support::Blake2_128Concat, Vec<u8>, (<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <T as frame_system::Config>::BlockNumber), frame_support::pallet_prelude::ValueQuery>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds

ensure!(Proofs::<T>::contains_key(&proof),Error::<T>::NoSuchProof);
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item cannot be called on `frame_support::pallet_prelude::StorageMap<_GeneratedPrefixForStorageProofs<T>, frame_support::Blake2_128Concat, Vec<u8>, (<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <T as frame_system::Config>::BlockNumber), frame_support::pallet_prelude::ValueQuery>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds

let (owner, _) = Proofs::<T>::get(&proof);
                              ^^^ function or associated item cannot be called on `frame_support::pallet_prelude::StorageMap<_GeneratedPrefixForStorageProofs<T>, frame_support::Blake2_128Concat, Vec<u8>, (<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <T as frame_system::Config>::BlockNumber), frame_support::pallet_prelude::ValueQuery>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds

Proofs::<T>::remove(&proof);
             ^^^^^^ function or associated item cannot be called on `frame_support::pallet_prelude::StorageMap<_GeneratedPrefixForStorageProofs<T>, frame_support::Blake2_128Concat, Vec<u8>, (<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <T as frame_system::Config>::BlockNumber), frame_support::pallet_prelude::ValueQuery>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds

 #[pallet::pallet]
           ^^^^^^ the trait `MaxEncodedLen` is not implemented for `Vec<u8>`

#[pallet::pallet]
          ^^^^^^ the trait `core::default::Default` is not implemented for `<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId`

#[pallet::storage]
          ^^^^^^^ the trait `core::default::Default` is not implemented for `<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId`
```

Can somebody please help me?
What should I do next??

Comment: The tutorial has been updated: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/use-macros-in-a-custom-pallet/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is a bug in the tutorial at the moment. While we work to fix it in the tutorial, here is a fix to the code:

```rust
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

// Re-export pallet items so that they can be accessed from the crate namespace.
pub use pallet::*;

#[frame_support::pallet]
pub mod pallet {
    use frame_support::pallet_prelude::*;
    use frame_system::pallet_prelude::*;

    #[pallet::pallet]
    #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
    pub struct Pallet<T>(_);

    /// Configure the pallet by specifying the parameters and types on which it depends.
    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
        /// Because this pallet emits events, it depends on the runtime's definition of an event.
        type Event: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Event>;
    }

    // Pallets use events to inform users when important changes are made.
    // Event documentation should end with an array that provides descriptive names for parameters.
    #[pallet::event]
    #[pallet::generate_deposit(pub(super) fn deposit_event)]
    pub enum Event<T: Config> {
        /// Event emitted when a claim has been created.
        ClaimCreated { who: T::AccountId, claim: T::Hash },
        /// Event emitted when a claim is revoked by the owner.
        ClaimRevoked { who: T::AccountId, claim: T::Hash },
    }

    #[pallet::error]
    pub enum Error<T> {
        /// The claim already exists.
        AlreadyClaimed,
        /// The claim does not exist, so it cannot be revoked.
        NoSuchClaim,
        /// The claim is owned by another account, so caller can't revoke it.
        NotClaimOwner,
    }

    #[pallet::storage]
    pub(super) type Claims<T: Config> =
        StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, T::Hash, (T::AccountId, T::BlockNumber)>;

    // Dispatchable functions allow users to interact with the pallet and invoke state changes.
    // These functions materialize as "extrinsics", which are often compared to transactions.
    // Dispatchable functions must be annotated with a weight and must return a DispatchResult.
    #[pallet::call]
    impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
        #[pallet::weight(0)]
        pub fn create_claim(origin: OriginFor<T>, claim: T::Hash) -> DispatchResult {
            // Check that the extrinsic was signed and get the signer.
            // This function will return an error if the extrinsic is not signed.
            let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;

            // Verify that the specified claim has not already been stored.
            ensure!(!Claims::<T>::contains_key(&claim), Error::<T>::AlreadyClaimed);

            // Get the block number from the FRAME System pallet.
            let current_block = <frame_system::Pallet<T>>::block_number();

            // Store the claim with the sender and block number.
            Claims::<T>::insert(&claim, (&sender, current_block));

            // Emit an event that the claim was created.
            Self::deposit_event(Event::ClaimCreated { who: sender, claim });

            Ok(())
        }

        #[pallet::weight(0)]
        pub fn revoke_claim(origin: OriginFor<T>, claim: T::Hash) -> DispatchResult {
            // Check that the extrinsic was signed and get the signer.
            // This function will return an error if the extrinsic is not signed.
            let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;

            // Get owner of the claim, if none return an error.
            let (owner, _) = Claims::<T>::get(&claim).ok_or(Error::<T>::NoSuchClaim)?;

            // Verify that sender of the current call is the claim owner.
            ensure!(sender == owner, Error::<T>::NotClaimOwner);

            // Remove claim from storage.
            Claims::<T>::remove(&claim);

            // Emit an event that the claim was erased.
            Self::deposit_event(Event::ClaimRevoked { who: sender, claim });
            Ok(())
        }
    }
}
```

Specifically, we switch the `StorageMap` from returning a value to returning an `Option<Value>`. We then handle that in the logic of the code.